Facing issue - java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory cannot be cast to class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
I am trying upgrade eclipse 4.23 to eclipse 4.31.
while doing this I am facing this issue.
I am using slf4j and logback version,

ch.qos.logback.classic_1.2.13.jar
ch.qos.logback.core_1.2.13.jar
slf4j.api_1.7.32.jar


SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory cannot be cast to class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext (org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @6e8966b; ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @6cc18f6e)

Thanks,

I also tried to upgrade both slf4j and logback latest version but no luck.

You just dropped an error message. For others to be able to help you, you need to describe what you actually did such that others can reproduce it. As always it depends, as there are two ways: see https://github.com/eclipse-packaging/packages/blob/0785450df94c886b7ee58b76d302f3eea2931a63/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product/epp.product#L266-L267 and https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator/blob/b2d6bdda0d3f7fbf8110e21ad52236db78eddc33/eclipse.platform.releng.tychoeclipsebuilder/eclipse.platform.repository/sdk.product#L200 Please show your product file.

Upgrade procedure may be broken. Can you just download a fresh copy of 4.31 and use that?
